# Why isn't my GoLang POST request being populated with data?

Tags: go

```
func forwarderHandlerFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    client := &http.Client{}
    u, _ := url.Parse(r.RequestURI)
    req, _ := http.NewRequest(r.Method, fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", apiUrl, u.Path), r.Body)
    fmt.Printf(fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", nutils.ReaderToString(req.Body)))
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    resp.Write(w)
}
```

I am trying to forward an incoming HTTP request to another endpoint, while copying the body, including POST/PUT form data into the new request.

However, it doesn't seem to work, even if the Body seems to print out correct with data.

Print output is:

> email=meh%!g(MISSING)mail.com

How can I fix it?

---

Edit: Added more debug info, this time, printing out the output of resp

```
func forwarderHandlerFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    client := &http.Client{}
    u, _ := url.Parse(r.RequestURI)

    req, _ := http.NewRequest(r.Method, fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", apiUrl, u.Path), r.Body)
    fmt.Printf(fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", nutils.ReaderToString(req.Body)))

    resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    b,_ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Printf(fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", nutils.BytesToString(b)))

    resp.Write(w)
}
```

> ```
> $ go install && gom-proxy-forwarder run --listen localhost:5002 --api-url http://localhost:5001
> email=meh2%!g(MISSING)mail.com
> {
>   "email": null
> }
> ```

It should not be null. It should be `meh@gmail.com`

Comment: What's the output of ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body) ?

Comment: Does this work if you comment out the `fmt.Printf(fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", nutils.ReaderToString(req.Body)))` line? `r.Body` should be of type `io.ReadCloser` so it's possible the stream is being closed after `r.Body` gets read by the `fmt.Printf` statement.

Comment: @Mike, tried it, didnt work.

Comment: I wonder ReverseProxy is going to help you? http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy

Comment: @baijum on top of trying to get it to work, but also trying to understand how net/http requests work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it. The problem was my endpoint in Python's Flask server does not support chunked encoding, which Go's Request insists on.

When I manually specified the ContentLength like `req.ContentLength = 25`, it worked.

Lesson learnt: It might not always be your Go code be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to set the request content type

```
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
```

reference http://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go?s=14234:14316#L450

Comment: tried it, doesn't work. can i copy the a Request Body and Header into the new Request? if so, how?

Comment: Did you really mean to copy the body? Because from your command, the `email` is in url param. Have you tried copy url params?

Comment: Yes, I mean to copy the body. it's not in the URL param. It's a POST form data.

Answer (score 0):

1. To fix your print output you need to change this:

   ```
   fmt.Printf(fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", nutils.ReaderToString(req.Body)))
   ```

   Into this:

   ```
   fmt.Printf("%s", fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", nutils.ReaderToString(req.Body)))
   ```

   Or this:

   ```
   fmt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("%s\n", nutils.ReaderToString(req.Body)))
   ```
2. By printing out the request body you are consuming it. Use a `TeeReader`:

   ```
   req, _ := http.NewRequest(r.Method, fmt.Sprintf("%s%s", apiUrl, u.Path), io.TeeReader(r.Body, os.Stdout))
   ```

   And get rid of the `nutils.ReaderToString` call. You can only read once from a `Reader` (unless it's also a `Seeker` but then you still need to  `Seek` it before reusing it)

Comment: thanks, got it. but removing the printlns, nothing works still.